# Proving qualities of Composite Functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

My discrete textbook asks:

> Let $f : X → Y$ and $g: Y → Z$. Is the following property true or
>   false? For all subsets **C** in **Z**, $\left(g\:◦\:f\right)^{-1\:}\left(C\right)=f^{-1}\left(g^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)$.
>   Justify your answer.

That the question is about subsets (instead of individual elements) throws me off. Also, if $\left(g\:◦\:f\right)^{-1\:}$ exists, that means f and g have to be bijective, right - or at least one-to-one? I'm not sure how to begin to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the bijectivity. To begin with, let $x\in(g\circ f)^{-1}(C)$, this means that $g\circ f(x)\in C$, now we see that $g(f(x))\in C$, so $f(x)\in Y$ is such that $g(f(x))\in C$, this means that $f(x)\in g^{-1}(C)$. Now $x\in X$ is such that $f(x)\in g^{-1}(C)$, which means that $x\in f^{-1}(g^{-1}(C))$. The other direction is treated similarly.